# How to write newline in qt

Tags: windows, linux, qt

I like to write linux newlines, under windows, but
QT automatically convert \n to \r\n based on the platform.

Any hints ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you speak of [QFile](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qfile.html#open-4)-s, you might pass an explicit [OpenMode](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qiodevice.html#OpenModeFlag-enum) to `open` which has its `QIODevice::Text` bit cleared.

Comment: @nfo: In this case "works like a charm" you may consider marking Basile's answer as "THE answer". It's both a sign of your appreciation and at the same time shows others that you don't need help with this any longer.